# Pivot Report Filter - if only one value avaliable select else ALL

Tags: vba, filter, pivot

[image]Requesting help I am currently working on a macro based pivot table where we have 5 columns in Report filter.
What I am looking for is vba code for these five filer, it should show the value if the filter contains a single value else should remain as (All).

Currently I am using the following code for pivot filer:

```
    Sub InsertPivotTable()

'Declare Variables
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

'Delete Preivous Pivot Table Worksheet & Insert a New Blank Worksheet With Same Name
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("Pivot").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "Pivot"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("Pivot")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Report")


'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
TableName:="ADT_PivotTable")

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="ADT_PivotTable")

'Insert Reportfilter Fields
   With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ADT_PivotTable").PivotFields("Resp Bus Partn ID")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ADT_PivotTable").PivotFields("ADT-File ID")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ADT_PivotTable").PivotFields("UWY")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ADT_PivotTable").PivotFields("SCoB - Acc")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ADT_PivotTable").PivotFields("Curr")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting an error with your code ? if yes what line ?

Comment: @ShaiRado no I am not getting any error at present the Pivot is showing the value as (ALL) by default, where as in the above 5 filters most of the filter will have only one value in it and no need of filter however because of the agreed standard format purpose we cannot remove the criteria from this filter but need to change manually.
So what I was looking for is the pivote filter should show the value automatically if it contain only one or single value else as default (All)

Answer (score 0):

The answer and code are a little long, but I've added a few "Bonuses" for you, so you'll find it very useful :)

**First**, there is no need to delete "Pivot" sheet and re-create it just to update the `PivotTable` named "ADT_PivotTable", you can just update the `PivotCache` with the updated `SourceData`, and afterwards refresh the `PivotTable` with the updated `PivotCache`.

**Second**, I’ve added a second `Sub`, that check for every `PivotField` passed to it how many `PivotItems` it has, if there’s only one `PivotItem` then display it in the Filter, Otherwise show "All".

***Sub InsertPivotTable* Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertPivotTable()

'Declare Variables
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

'Delete Preivous Pivot Table Worksheet & Insert a New Blank Worksheet With Same Name
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set PSheet = Worksheets("Pivot")
On Error GoTo 0
If PSheet Is Nothing Then ' if "Pivot" sheet doesn't exist
    Set PSheet = Sheets.Add(Before:=ActiveSheet)
    PSheet.Name = "Pivot"
End If
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Set DSheet = Worksheets("Report")
'Define Data Range
With DSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = .Range("A1").Resize(LastRow, LastCol) ' set data range for Pivot Table
End With

' Set the Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

On Error Resume Next
Set PTable = PSheet.PivotTables("ADT_PivotTable") ' Set the Pivot Table if already exists from previous code runs

On Error GoTo 0
If PTable Is Nothing Then ' <-- Pivot Table still doesn't exist >> create it for the first time
    ' create a new Pivot Table in "Pivot" sheet
    Set PTable = PSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PCache, TableDestination:=PSheet.Range("A1"), TableName:="ADT_PivotTable")

    With PTable
        'Insert Reportfilter Fields
        With .PivotFields("Resp Bus Partn ID")
            .Orientation = xlPageField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        With .PivotFields("ADT-File ID")
            .Orientation = xlPageField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        With .PivotFields("UWY")
            .Orientation = xlPageField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        With .PivotFields("SCoB - Acc")
            .Orientation = xlPageField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        With .PivotFields("Curr")
            .Orientation = xlPageField
            .Position = 1
        End With
    End With
Else
    ' just refresh the Pivot cache with the updated Range
    PTable.ChangePivotCache PCache
    PTable.RefreshTable
End If

' modify the Filter default view for each of the Pivot Fields below
With PTable
    SelectFilterSingleValue .PivotFields("Resp Bus Partn ID")
    SelectFilterSingleValue .PivotFields("ADT-File ID")
    SelectFilterSingleValue .PivotFields("UWY")
    SelectFilterSingleValue .PivotFields("SCoB - Acc")
    SelectFilterSingleValue .PivotFields("Curr")
End With

End Sub
```

***Sub SelectFilterSingleValue* Code**

```
Sub SelectFilterSingleValue(ptFld As PivotField)

Dim PTItm       As PivotItem
Dim Count       As Long

With ptFld
    .EnableMultiplePageItems = True

    For Each PTItm In .PivotItems
        If PTItm.Name <> "(blank)" Then
            PTItm.Visible = True
            Count = Count + 1
        Else
            PTItm.Visible = False
        End If
    Next PTItm

    If Count > 1 Then
        .ClearAllFilters
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts :) and tried the code to but the "Sub SelectFilterSingleValue Code" its not working for me. not getting any error but its not reflecting in the pivot.

Comment: @Sanoj maybe I'm not understanding what you want, cause it did something for my Filters (maybe not what you wanted to), can you edit your post and add a screen-shot of how you would like to`PivotTable` and filters to look like (even manualy)

Comment: I have added a screen shot in my initial post. Where you could see few filters with numbers and some as (All). 
Here, (All) is default because this filter contain more than one value in the dropdown list. Where as the first filter is selected as 00705 because it has only one value in the dropdown list.
Please note: its not always the first filter will have a single value it may change to multiple values in dropdown list in any of the above 5 filters.

Comment: @Sanoj  are these fields formatted as numeric, or text ?

Comment: The first 3 are numeric and last two are text.

Comment: Also, was wondering if I could insert one more pivot table in next +1 column available.

Comment: @Sanoj If you must, use a **DECENT** gap, in case your current `PivotTable` will "grow" a few columns, I would put it at least 4-5 coluns to the right

Comment: @Sanoj didn;t get the chance yet to continue,did you get it resolved ?